# Edit webform submission secure token url

Tags: webforms, 9

I would like to change url for secure token.
Now it `/webform/MYFORM/submissions/sid?token`

But i would like to change it to `/submissions/sid?token`

I use these instructions https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2979091 but could't modify path.
If I use `OutboundPathProcessorInterface`I get 404.

How can I achieve this?

**WHAT I'VE DONE**

I create `mymodule.services.yml` with:

```
services:
  mymodule.link_modifier_service:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\LinkModifierService
    tags:
      - { name: path_processor_inbound, priority: 300 } 
      - { name: path_processor_outbound, priority: 300 }  
    arguments: ['@request_stack']
```

Put in `src` folder `LinkModifierService.php` with:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\InboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\OutboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;


/**
 * Class DefaultService.
 */
class LinkModifierService implements InboundPathProcessorInterface, OutboundPathProcessorInterface {

  /**
   * Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack definition.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack
   */
  protected $requestStack;
  /**
   * Constructs a new DefaultService object.
   */
  public function __construct(RequestStack $request_stack) {
    $this->requestStack = $request_stack;
  }
  
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function processInbound($path, Request $request = NULL) {
    if (strpos($path, '/submission/') === 0) {
      $sid = str_replace('/submission/', '', $path);
      $path = "/webform/MYFORM/submissions/" . $sid;
    }
    return $path;
  }  
  
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function processOutbound($path, &$options = array(), Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {
  
    if (empty($request)) {
      $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    }
    if (strpos($path, '/webform/MYFORM/submissions/') === 0) {
      $sid = str_replace('/webform/MYFORM/submissions/', '', $path);
      $path = "/submission/" . $sid;
    }

    return $path;
  }
  
}
```

Now I could get `/submission/sid?token`but I could't change first part of this url. I need `MYFORM/sid?token` without word 'submission'.

Comment: Those are not instructions. They are the maintainer saying that people should write custom code and people posting some things that they tried. As written this question is unanswerable because we don’t know what you did.

Comment: I add all I've done in my question and I just need to change 'submission' in fron of url.